# How to determine the path router of swapExactTokensForTokens

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap, swaps

I am using the method: `swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)`.
How to determine the path router of a swap in `address[] calldata path`
Someone's path is 3 addresses, another is 2 addresses

Answer (score 2):

if i got your question correctly, you would like to determine when have 2 address or 3 address in your path.

There are instances where you would like to trade your **tokenA** and **tokenB** through WETH. That is from tokenA to WETH then from WETH to tokenB. The reason being, some times it results in a better price. In such cases your path will have 3 Addresses [tokenA, WETH, tokenB].

If you want a direct swap or one of your token pools has WETH already then you can have two addresses. Find below snippet on how you can check and choose between 3 addresses and 2 address.

```
    address[] memory path;
    if (tokenA == WETH || tokenB == WETH) {
      path = new address[](2);
      path[0] = tokenA;
      path[1] = tokenB;
    } else {
      path = new address[](3);
      path[0] = tokenA;
      path[1] = WETH;
      path[2] = tokenB;
    }
```

Comment: Thank for you answer. I take the example of FLURRY. It has 3 pairs of liquidity
    `FLURRY/WBNB FLURRY/BUSD FLURRY/USDT`.
I use swap coin98 [link here](https://exchange.coin98.com/pancakeswap/0x47c9BcEf4fE2dBcdf3Abf508f147f1bBE8d4fEf2).
Case 1: Swap `BUSD => FLURRY`, its path is `BUSD > USDC > FLURRY`.
Case 2: Swap `USDT => FLURRY`, its path `USDT > UST > USDC > FLURRY`.
Both Case1 and Case2 confuse me